# "Invalid Token" in ci-merchant with paypal

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, ci-merchant

I am trying to integrate paypal payment module with one of my application. For that I used ci-merchant. I did the following code:

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->helper('language');
$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('merchant_paypal_express');

$settings = array(
        'username' => 'amas***-facilitator_api1.opl****.com',
        'password' => '1383***828',
        'signature' => 'AQU0e5vuZCvSg*****oSa.sGUDlpAdkd1coWah3Y.Bvq-lz3WLKI-t-q',
        'test_mode' => true);

$this->merchant->initialize($settings);

$params = array(
    'amount' => 100.00,
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'return_url' => base_url().'payment',
    'cancel_url' => base_url().'payment'
);

$response = $this->merchant->purchase_return($params);
var_dump($response);
```

It gives me the following result:

```
object(Merchant_response)[23]
  protected '_status' => string 'failed' (length=6)
  protected '_message' => string 'Invalid token.' (length=14)
  protected '_reference' => null
  protected '_data' => null
  protected '_redirect_url' => null
  protected '_redirect_method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  protected '_redirect_message' => null
  protected '_redirect_data' => null
```

Some one please tell me about **Invalid token** error and about what is the best way to use ci-merchat.

Comment: @Adrian Macneil Could you please give me a solution.

Comment: Btw is there a reason you aren't using Omnipay? CI-merchant is unsupported and won't be receiving any further development.

Comment: Why are you calling purchase_return()? You need to call purchase() first.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil Thanks a lot. I will use Omnipay in my next project.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

$settings = $this->merchant->default_settings();

and After that

$settings = array('username' => 'amas***-facilitator_api1.opl****.com',

```
              'password' => '1383***828',

              'signature' => 'AQU0e5vuZCvSg*****oSa.sGUDlpAdkd1coWah3Y.Bvq-lz3WLKI-t-q',
     'test_mode' => true)
```

;

Comment: I could not understand your point. Why I need to use default_settings while I used custom settings already? Btw I got my answer from comment.